# Missing icons in published version Sitecore temp iconcache

Tags: caching, sitecore, sitecore8.1

The published version of an item in Sitecore 8.1 has many missing icons with text, publishing only the title and a short description.

In validation, it shows:

> An error occurred while validating: The 'Value'

followed by many instances of `temp/iconcache/` items at the end of the error it says that part of the cookie is invalid.

In preview, the items looks just fine, but between that, and publishing it breaks, believing it's related to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you request an icon for the first time it stores in *temp/iconcache/* folder and all the following requests will be servered from that cache. *temp/iconcache/* folders never get cleared automatically, therefore, I would recommend to delete them manually and then re-publish icons again.

Also please make sure that you have the correct declaration for icon handler *sitecore_icon.ashx* in your config files (i.e. as in original Sitecore configs).